# Changing header logo href for the checkout page

Tags: hooks, logo

I am trying to change the href of the logo to a specific custom URL other than the homepage for checkout page.

I have tried few methods including the one shown below but did not work :

```
add_filter( 'generate_logo_href','generate_add_custom_logo_href' );
function generate_add_custom_logo_href()
{
if  ( is_checkout()) {
        return 'https://www.custom.de/customurl';
   }
    else {
    return 'https://www.custom.de/';
    }
}
```

This is the block of the logo. I am trying to change the href associated with the anchor tag :

```
    <div id="logo" class="flex-col logo"> <!-- Header logo -->
    <a href="https://custom.com" title="Title" rel="home">
        <img width="213" height="89" src="https://custom/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Logo1.svg" class="header_logo header-logo" alt="text">
        <img width="213" height="89" src="https://custom/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Logo2.svg" class="header-logo-dark" alt="text">
</a>

</div>
```

Is there any other hooks specifically for this purpose? I am using flatsome theme.

Comment: It depends on how your theme adds the link to begin with. There's preferred ways, but there's no guarantee your theme used them. You should contact the theme author.

Comment: If you want to change the behaviour of a theme, the recommended way is to create a child theme. Have you looked into this yet?